# Jar launches when clicked but not from processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am making a game in lwjgl, and I exported the jar for it. I put all the natives in the same folder as it, and if you click the jar it runs fine. However, if I do

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Djava.library.path="+pathtonativefolder, "-jar", pathtojar);
```

Then it doesn't launch. However, when I do

```
java -Djava.library.path=nativesfolder -jar thejar.jar
```

It works fine. What's happening? I assume it's not setting the java.library.path correctly.

Comment: The `jar` must be followed by a jar, you can't but the `-D` after the `-jar`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It still doesn't work if I change it to ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Djava.library.path="+pathtonativefolder, "-jar" ,pathtojar);

Comment: The command you build is not the command that works.  Also, consider giving full path to java binary.

Comment: Maybe the native code is sensitive to the current working directory? Does it work if you use `pb.directory` to set the cwd for the command to the same value as when you run it from the command line?

Comment: @IanRoberts Nope, that doesn't work either.

Comment: What Exception or output do you get when you start the process? Are you using [`inheritIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29)?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you do call [`pb.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start--), don't you?

Comment: @siegi :P yes I do. Thanks for asking though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I do not get any exceptions or stacktraces, and I am not using inheritIO. Would inheritIO be useful?

Comment: @user3042719 Did you try `inheritIO` and see [Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out I was trying to launch a Java 1.8 jar from a 1.7 project. Silly me.

Comment: I don't understand why this should not work: You start a new `java` process. The Java version of the original application (i.e. the one calling the `ProcessBuilder`) should not matter, as long as the `java` command points to the correct executable (i.e. the one of Java 8)... Am I missing something?

Comment: @siegi Well, I changed the project from 1.7 to 1.8 and it worked. I don't know.